# How to update availability for "Ready For Sale" app on iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, itunes

We have one app version 1.1.2 on App Store which is in \"Ready For Sale\" state. This app was NOT launched for China. However we want to launch the same app to Chinese app store also with Chinese publication details.

Can we launch the same app version 1.1.2 to Chinese app store with adding Chinese publication details.

OR

Do we need to launch the new version of app (say 1.1.3) including china with other countries. I really want to avoid this option.

OR

Can we launch the new version(1.1.3) for China only with version 1.1.2 visible for other countries.

Can anybody please suggest me the way out of this.

regards,

Varun Mehta

Answer (score 0):

Don't think its related to your build, just simply update the available country region from the `Pricing and availability` section and the Chinese description in `App Information`'s `Localizable Information` section

Only when you want to change or update your build file then need to update the version

Comment: Tj3n,

App description field is coming disabled which is restricted me to add localised version for new country (China)

Comment: Have you tried to click the `English(US)` button on the right of `Localizable Information`? It should have Chinese after u made it available, else probably you should try submit new version

Comment: Yes I have tried that also. 

I think we can not update :-( Se my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Just gone through this update link from apple under warning inside itunes connect.

[image]

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/product-page/

Its mentioned

***"You can update your app’s description when you submit a new version of your app. If you want to share important updates more frequently, consider using your promotional text instead."***

So i think we can not update app description for Ready For Sale apps.

**UPDATE:**

Apple has confirmed with their response to my ticket that we need to submit new app if we want to add more country of availability or localisation.

**App Review Team Reply:**

```
To answer your question about the metadata, please note that from iOS 11 the description metadata is locked, which means that you will need to submit a new version with the Chinese description.
```